# Toolbar no se colapsa con RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

tengo una actividad en la que uso un RecyclerView, estoy intentando que al hacer scroll sobre el RecyclerView la barra de android se colapse, he probado usando NestedScrollView, pero al tener muchos elementos en el RecyclerView se ralentizaba la actividad.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        app:contentScrim="@color/semi_transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="?attr/nav_background_drawable"
            android:id="@+id/background"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".myactivity"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_crono"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_charts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_chart"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe varias razones, la primera, un bug conocido que fue solucionado en la versión 23.1.0:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176673&q=collapsingToolbarLayout%20scroll&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Otra causa es que no se tenga la propiedad `app:layout_scrollFlags` y la bandera `scroll` definida en el `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
```

Otra causa que explicitamente no se permita el scroll en tu [RecyclerView:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), por lo que debe estar habilitado:

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Encontré el problema tenia:

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Y cambié a:

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Me alegroq eu lo hayas solucionado. Cuando te deje el sistema, marca la pregunta como resuelta